# Pass argument from controller to service with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a service which performs an HTTP call and gets some data to a particular URL.
What I am trying to do is to pass an argument from the Controller to the Service and use it as parameter in my URI.

For example, my call now is api.myurl.com/foo and I want to make it api.myurl.com/foo/bar

Where *bar* is user's input from a search form.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

*Service*

```
angular.module('MyApp').service('MyMapper', function(MyService, $http, $q, API_TR_URL, _, PAGINATION_LIMITS) {
function MyMapper() {}

    MyMapper.prototype.find = function(params) {
    var p = angular.copy(params);
    p.limit = PAGINATION_LIMITS.myResolver;
    var d = $q.defer();

    var requestURL = API_TR_URL + '/app_dev.php/entities/' + param;

        $http.get(requestURL)
        .success(function(results)
        {
            console.log('Results data  entities: ', results.data.data.entities);
           for (var entitiesIndex in results.data.data.entities)
           {
               var preparedData = results.data.data.entities[entitiesIndex];
               results.data.data.entities[entityIndex] = new Entity(preparedData);
           }

           d.resolve(results);
        })
        .error(function(status)
        {
            d.reject(arguments);
        });

    return d.promise;
    };

return new MyMapper();
});
```

and the *Controller* like this:

```
angular.module('MyBackendApp')
.controller('MySearchFormController', ['$scope', 'API_TR_URL', 'MyMapper', '$location', function($scope,  MyMapper, $location){
    $scope.submit = function (){

            console.log('-- Search string: '+ $scope.entityName);

            var entitiesCount = Object.keys(data.data.data.entities).length;
            $scope.totalPagesNum = Math.ceil( entitiesCount / 10);
            $scope.page = data.page;

            var d = $q.defer();

            // Build the  results
            $scope.entitiesResults = (function listEntities(entities, $scope){

                var entities = data.data.data.entities;

                if ( (typeof entities === 'undefined') || (entities.length === 0) ){
                    return null;
                }

                return entities;
            })();


    }
}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No where in your *controller* do you use your reference to the `MyMapper` variable but `MyMapper` is an instance of `MyMapper` and therefore has a `find` *function*. So in your *controller* you can have the following code

```
var promise = MyMapper.find({param1:1,param2:"a"});
```

Which calls the `find` *function* of the `MyMapper` *object* and stores the *promise* returned by the *function*. You can then listen for the result of the *promise* like so

```
promise.then(function(entities) {
    //TODO ON SUCCESS
}, function(errorMsg) {
    //TODO ON FAIL
});
```

Also I think you should use the `factory` function instead of `service`.

This is all you need (provided given that everything compiles for the Javascript and registers for the Angular).

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggested.
So, I am passing the entity name like this : MyMapper.find({param: $scope.a}); 

How do I access it in the Factory to include it in the following URL?
 var requestURL = API_TR_URL + '/app_dev.php/entities/' + param; ?

I do not see able to use it.

Comment: well you could either make `find` take another argument (`param`) or reference `params.param` or `p.param` (since `p` is a copy of `params`) in `find`

Comment: It seems that currently MyMapper factory is not even called. I need to debug it.

Comment: Maybe because it is dependent on 4 other services that may not exist? `MyService, API_TR_URL, _, PAGINATION_LIMITS`. The console (F12) should be of some use for figuring this out.

Comment: I am passing the searchString as follows:
MyMapper.prototype.find = function(params, searchString) { ...}

but still I cannot access it in the Factory: 

angular.module('MyBackendApp').factory('MyMapper', function(Entity, $http, $q, API_TR_URL) {
    function MyMapper() {}
   MyMapper.prototype.find = function(params, searchString) { ...}

Any thoughts?

AS you understand, I am new to Angular